# All duplicate words

Tags: java, .net, regex

I need to find ALL duplicate words.
For example:

```
"abc some word abc eee word abc"
```

should match:

```
abc abc abc word word
```

OR

```
abc word abc word abc
```

I've tried: `"(\b\w+\b)(?=.*?\b\1\b)"` but it doesn't match last duplicate words.

p.s
Does it possible to find all duplicates using regex (java or .net regex engine)?

Comment: because `(?=.*?\b\1\b)` is an assertion, it won't match any character.

Comment: Say it is possible; why would you want to do it with a regex? Is performance irrelevant?

Comment: specifically for this task - performance doesn't matter. The main goal - do it using regex (or almost regex)

Comment: Why don't you scanner the text input and build a Map<String,Integer> as suggested by EddyG

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regular expression, I would suggest to simply use a

```
Map<String, Integer>
```

The keys are the words that you parse from your text; the value represents a counter (for the number of occurrences ). Initialize the counter with 1; and increase when you find the same word again.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(\w+)\b(?=(?:(?!\b\1\b).)*\b(\1)\b(?:(?!\b\1\b).)*$)|\b(\w+)\b(?=.*?\b\3\b)
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the `captures` or `groups`.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/31

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @vks can be simplified like so `(\w+)(?=(?:(?!\1).)*\b(\1)\b)`

See below for the example.

https://regex101.com/r/3G5XV8/1